# GET method perfomance

Tags: python, python-requests, get, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I made a Python3 script to download an arbitrary number of CSV files (61 in this case) from a web server located in LAN, using `requests` module.
The download happening in CPU-bounds, and it takes about 2:54 minutes (more than 2.85 seconds per file).

CSV names are example `f'name{index}'` so I can iterate through them with an index.

**My question, is there a way to improve the execution time?**

## 1. For loop - 2:54 minutes

```
   for file in range(0, files_to_process):
        nome_CSV = f'costantName_{file}.csv'
        # If file exist, delete it to then recreate it.
        if os.path.exists(nome_CSV):
            os.remove(nome_CSV)

        url = f"http://{self.ip}/this_is_the_path/{nome_CSV}"
        try:
            # This web server doesn't support cookies.
            r = requests.get(
                url=url,
                auth=(self.user, self.password),
                allow_redirects=True,
                headers=headers
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            continue
        # Save the file locally
        open(nome_CSV, "wb").write(r.content)
```

## 2. Threads/Processes - Not defined

### Thread/Process part

```
#with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
    # CSV_names is a list with 60 names (constructed with a comprehension)
    for name in CSV_names:
        url = "This_is_an_URL" + name
        futures = [executor.submit(self.get_file, url, name)]
    done, not_done = wait(futures, return_when=concurrent.futures.ALL_COMPLETED)
```

### Request part

```
def download_url(self, url: str):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1)'
                             ' AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
                             ' Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    try:
        data = requests.get(
            url=url,
            auth=(self.user, self.password),
            allow_redirects=True,
            headers=headers
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None
    else:
        return data.content
```

### Save file part

```
def save_file(file_name: str, data, path):
    out_path = os.path.join(path, file_name)
    with open(out_path, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(data)
    return out_path
```

In the new version, I've tried `Multithreading` vs `Multiprocessing` vs a new "normal" version.

For my machine, which is a CPU Intel Core I5-8265U 1.60GHz with 16 GB RAM, results are (in minutes):

| Threads/Processes | Multi-processing | Multi-threading |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | **02:39**:122703 | **02:39**:305354 |
| 16 | **02:33**:569016 | **02:29**:909762 |

Normal execution takes always **02:44**:662881 to execute (milliseconds of difference).

I think that I've gained few seconds by using `with` keyword and `comprehensions` when possible.
By raising number of threads/processes I've gained even more seconds.

Comment: Yes, parallelizing the tasks is the way to go. https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Comment: I've tried with ThreadPoolExecutor, but without any performance improvements (GIL is the cause I think). I will try processes in parallel now.

Comment: How long does it take when just downloading one file? (not total duration divided by number of files, but literally just running the code for one file)

Comment: How big are these files?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Files are `3.143 KB` each. To download one file, with 8 threads/processes it takes 3 seconds per file, while in "normal" (no processes/threads) execution we have 2.5 seconds.